# Launching systemd unit on resume, which tracks docker container running

Tags: systemd, dependencies

My use case is the following:

I have a very power hungry machine as part of my CI (a worker). I want to power down this worker.

Currently the docker container is spun up via a systemd unit file and of type `simple`.

I tried to make this unit file respond to suspend and resume, but I think this is not possible.

Attempting to solve the problem of having systemd track the docker container yet being able to start it on suspend and stop it on resume seems to be a whole different thing.

One idea was to start a systemd unit from a systemd unit.

Can this be modeled better than above using systemd unit files and dependencies?

Comment: “I tried to make this unit file respond to suspend and resume” Why? The worker should just reconnect and that’s it.

Comment: Theory, in practice the worker tends to freeze on resume and never connect. Thus this dance around the fire.